# Can the Phantasmal Killer spell be cast on a target on the other side of a Wall of Force?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cover, wall

Wizard 1 casts [*wall of force*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-force) which surrounds Wizard 2. Now both wizards have full cover against each other. For example, now they cannot cast *fireball* against each other, because "nothing can physically pass through the wall" per its rules.

But what about [*phantasmal killer*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/phantasmal-killer)? From description:

> You tap into the nightmares of a creature you can see within range and create an illusory manifestation of its deepest fears, visible only to that creature

I think *wall of force* does not help against *phantasmal killer* because nothing is physically passing through the wall, but I wanted to confirm if that's how RAW works here.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No.  You need a [clear path to the target](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AClearPathtotheTarget)

> To target something, you must have a clear path to it, so it can't be behind total cover.

Being behind a *wall of force* constitutes total [cover](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Cover), so the wizards can't target one another.

[This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/99048/38434) further elucidates the subject with a link to a podcast by Jeremy Crawford discussing a window blocking spell targeting.

Comment: This answer should include the reasoning of why Wall of Force would grant total cover.

Comment: @Akixkisu linked to cover for convenience.  It specifically calls out a wall as providing cover.

Comment: Then you should make that distinct in your answer. While links are helpful the actual argument and reasoning should be clear, generally brevity is acceptable but not at the cost of a full explanation which is always better (see good answer faq).

Comment: The relevant quote from the cover rules: "**Walls**, trees, creatures, and other obstacles can provide cover during combat, making a target more difficult to harm." _Wall of Force_, as its name suggests, makes a wall.

Comment: @Akixkisu The premise of the question is that Wall of Force grants total cover, so it's not something that needs to be proven here.

Comment: @Miniman the premise of the question can be correct or incorrect and we are doing better work if we affirm or deny the established premise. Recently you have done this [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/147458/44723), [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/138363/44723) and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/150246/44723)